# Yammer App Url Schema

Tags: ios, cordova, yammer

I want to open the yammer iOS app from within my (Cordova) application, which can be done with the InAppBrowserPlugin and the following URL:

```
window.open('yammer://threads')
```

This opens the yammer app and navigates to any network (the most recent used network within the app). Is it possible to open the yammer iOS app and directly jump into the home screen of a specific network?

for example (does not work):

```
yammer://mynetworkname/threads
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't supported by the Yammer iOS app at this time.

Comment: Have you tried using a mobile deep link? https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android